# DropdownButton tries to recreate with items from another class in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I've put several DropdownButton in my app like this:

[image]

And user can switch between layouts through a switch button: **Pessoal or Equipe**

[image]

Those dropdownButton are all populated with data from an API with a code like
this:

```
FutureBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>(                                                       
 future: loadColaboradores(),                                                                    
 builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {           
   if (!snapshot.hasData)                                                                        
      return CircularProgressIndicator();                                                        
   else                                                                                          
     return Expanded(                                                                            
       child: DropdownButton<String>(                                                            
       isExpanded: true,                                                                         
       value: _responsavelSelecionado,                                                           
       onChanged: (String newValue) {                                                            
         var arr = newValue.split('|');                                                          
         setState(() {                                                                           
           _responsavelSelecionado = newValue;                                                   
         });                                                                                     
       },                                                                                        
       items: snapshot.data.map((Map map) {                                                      
           return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(                                                  
           value: map["nome"].toString().inCaps + "|" + map["fotoUrl"].toString(),               
           child: FittedBox(                                                                     
               child: Row(children: <Widget>[                                                    
             Container(                                                                          
                 width: 35.0,                                                                    
                 height: 35.0,                                                                   
                 decoration: new BoxDecoration(                                                  
                     shape: BoxShape.circle,                                                     
                     image: new DecorationImage(                                                 
                         fit: BoxFit.fill, image: new NetworkImage(map["fotoUrl"])))),           
             SizedBox(                                                                           
               width: 10,                                                                        
             ),                                                                                  
             Text(map["nome"].toString().inCaps,                                                 
                 style:                                                                          
                     TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                 overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis)                                                
           ])),                                                                                  
         );                                                                                      
       }).toList(),                                                                              
     ));                                                                                         
 })
```

All of them have its own class and the API is called in separated methods.

If I navigate to the screen back and forth it works ok.

But if I switch the layouts flutter tries to populate the other DropdownMenu with
items from the other classes. And you can see several items that don't belong
to that class in the place where after a while will be populated with the
right ones.

[image]

Look at: Equipe Black Hole

Black Hole should not be at equipe because it belongs to Meta as we can see there.

But Responsável is worse because it has pictures and when it tries to render the pictures
with wrong class it crashes and shows that message of Overflowed pixels.

This happens in the first line of the menu and last until Flutter fills all the option then
the app goes back to normal.

I've tried a lot of things here but no success till now to avoid this. Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: Not sure I understand your issue completly. But you might be having some issues because you are using snapshot.hasdata. Just because it has data doesn't mean it completed the download of all the data. Instead snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done might be better...

Comment: You're right. That's exactly the problem. Now I'm testing both of them 'if ((snapshot.hasData ) && ( snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done ))' and it's working

Comment: Sweet glad you got it working.

Comment: Actually the problem isn't because it didn't finish the download yet, but it uses the data from another Dropdownmenu. Now I'm testing ConnectionState and even though it has data,  the ConnectionState is waiting. To wait till ConnectionState is done give it time to update data before rendering the widget on the screen.

Comment: How are you "switching" from one view to another if not using the navigator? using visible? replacing the view with another? ... migth be a Key issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing if the problem is not in how you populate the single dropdown button but above. Are you using stateful widgets to wrap the widget containing the dropdown button? If so, are you using Keys to correctly handle how they are rendered?

If you are using a Widget like a listView (or a Column, row, etc.), and then you put inside that listview stateful widgets, is important to use keys. Otherwise, when you repopulate that ListView, you might have unwanted behaviours.

Eventually, for more information on keys, there's this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc&t=98s